# Convert case class containing objects containing mutableMap to json and back using lift

Tags: json, lift, mutablemap

I have a case class as :

```
case class Cart(cart_id :UUID, cart_entries :Map[String,CartEntry]){

  //override def toString: String = "Saini CartId = " + cart_id.toString

}
```

I am using net.liftweb.json._ to convert this into json :

```
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new UUIDserializer
val json = write(cart)
println(json)
```

the Json comes out as

```
{"cart_id":"68eb787f-746c-4320-9ef4-8b5c7f0d7e21","cart_entries":[{"_1":"ABC","_2":{"sku_id":"ABC","quantity":12,"price":213.0}}]}
```

While converting back my json to a cart object :

```
val jValue = read[Cart](json)
```

I am getting this exception .

> [ERROR] [12/22/2016 17:11:23.784]
>   [System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
>   [akka://System/user/68eb787f-746c-4320-9ef4-8b5c7f0d7e21] No usable
>   value for cart_entries
>       No constructor for type interface scala.collection.mutable.Map, JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(_1,JString(ABC)),
>   JField(_2,JObject(List(JField(sku_id,JString(ABC)),
>   JField(quantity,JInt(12)), JField(price,JDouble(213.0)))))))))
>       net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for cart_entries
>       No constructor for type interface scala.collection.mutable.Map, JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(_1,JString(ABC)),
>   JField(_2,JObject(List(JField(sku_id,JString(ABC)),
>   JField(quantity,JInt(12)), JField(price,JDouble(213.0)))))))))
>         at net.liftweb.json.Meta$.fail(Meta.scala:191)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.mkValue$1(Extraction.scala:357)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$build$1(Extraction.scala:317)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$$anonfun$14.apply(Extraction.scala:253)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$$anonfun$14.apply(Extraction.scala:253)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.instantiate$1(Extraction.scala:253)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.newInstance$1(Extraction.scala:286)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$build$1(Extraction.scala:315)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$extract0(Extraction.scala:366)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$extract0(Extraction.scala:199)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:43)
>         at net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:312)
>         at net.liftweb.json.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:58)
>         at What should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cart_entries field is defined as `scala.collection.mutable.Map`.  Lift's JSON serialization knows how to serialize a Map (mutable or immutable), but it doesn't know how to deserialize into a mutable Map.  To fix it, either define your map to be `scala.collection.immutable.Map` or add `TypeHints` to your formats to support the mutable type.

Comment: Can please you share code to add TypeHints to support the mutable type?